# How to show 1 or 2 column layout using lightning-layout-item size attribute

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am passing dynamic layout attribute as `1` or `2` to show a 1 column grid layout vs 2 column grid layout.

When going through `lightning-layout-item` size attribute I saw that it actually always divides the value by 12 and then shows it. Now if I pass 1 or 2, it becomes 1-12 size and 2-12 size.
As I am passing Object directly to UI is it possible from front end to change this to size 6-12 and size 12-12:

```
<template>
    <lightning-spinner class={spinnerClass} alternative-text="Loading" size="large"></lightning-spinner>
    <template for:each={lstArticles} for:item="eachArticle">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="false" key={eachArticle.objHelpArticle.Id}>
            <template for:each={eachArticle.lstHelpSections} for:item="eachArticleSection">
                <lightning-layout-item size={eachArticle.objHelpArticle.Layout__c} key={eachArticleSection.Id}>
                    <div class="custom-box slds-box slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_center"><lightning-formatted-rich-text
                            value={eachArticleSection.Content__c}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                    </div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout>
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do any calculations, so you'd have to do some processing to change it to 12 (for 1 column) and 6 (for 2 columns). Something like:

```
this.lstArticles
  .forEach((article) => {
    article.objHelpArticle
      .forEach((helpArticle) => {
        helpArticle.columnSize = 12/parseInt(helpArticle.Layout__c);
      })
  });
```

You may need to copy the data if using an @api attribute, and I kind of guessed about the layout of your data, as the names and iterations you're using seem off, but this should help you get started.

Comment: yeah thought of change the backend to wrapper to accommodate this. But this works too. `result.forEach((article) => {
                    article.objHelpArticle.Layout__c = 12 / parseInt(article.objHelpArticle.Layout__c);
            });`